# Force Chrome password update

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, passwords, change-password

I made a profile page where users can update their passwords:

```
<form action="..." method="post">
  New password: <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password" name="password1" />
  Repeat: <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password" name="password2" />
  <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

The issue is that when they validate the form, Chrome is not suggesting to update the password in its password manager.

I know that on some websites, when I change my password, Chrome automatically detects it and suggests to update it in the password manager.

How can I force Chrome to take into account this new password?

I tried playing around with the `autocomplete` attribute, or adding a field requesting the old password, but nothing seems to work…

**The only way to make Chrome show the password update pop-up is to redirect the user to a different URL after the password change.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect the user to another url by writing in

header(location: theLocationHere)

write that under the change password code in php

redirect him to the home to be nice

Comment: Thanks I figured that out, but how to avoid redirecting to another location? I just need the user to stay on the same page.